# How to do error handling testing with mockmvc?

Tags: java, exception, junit5, mockmvc

I have a method and method includes one exception if some param does not write in url. Let's show below

```
if (url != null) {
File = getService().getByUrl(url);
} else {
throw new IllegalStateException("you must send id);
}
```

this is my method pair and I want to write test for exception. How to I cath error message with mockmvc?

```
return getMockMvc().perform(get(url))
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
.andExpect(status().is5xxServerError());
```

This code not getting with error message. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
return getMockMvc().perform(get(url)) .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8) .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
andExpect(content().string(containsString("you must send id")));
```

Comment: `try{
            getMockMvc().perform(get(url))
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
.andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())          .andExpect(content().string("you must send id"));
        } 
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`
I solved problem use this small code

Comment: Hi, Selo. Thanks for the feedback. If the answer help you, please mark this answer as "correct answer".